# Magento 2.3.5-p1 blank checkout

Tags: magento2.3, shopping-cart

I have installed `Magento 2.3.5-p1`, and to test the default `order/checkout`. I added an item to the cart, however, the shopping cart button shows nothing but a blank popup as shown in the image below.

[image]

Moreover, if I go manually on the cart page, I can see the order, and when I click `checkout` I get nothing but a blank page. `https://www.domain.com/checkout/#shipping`

**Logs**:

```
-bash-4.2$ tail -40 connector.log 
[2020-07-12 06:17:00] dotdigital.INFO: ERROR Creditmemo Order not found :2, quote id : 2, store id 1 [] []
```

Nginx error logs have nothing with regard to this. I have also given correct permission i.e.

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: yes, I disabled page_speed module in nginx config. and I re installed a fresh copy of magento via composer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, I disabled `page_speed` module in nginx config. and I re installed a fresh copy of magento via composer.